Valgrind: how to find the stack variable that is detected as not initalized?
UPDATE-1: made the example a little more realistic
SUSE Tumbleweed, clang 19.1.4, gcc 14.2.1, valgrind 3.24.0 (built from source)
in my_proc.cpp
int proc()
{
    int y;
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int y = proc();
    int x;
    return x+y;
}

using g++ and valgrind
g++ -g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer my_prog.cpp
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=no --track-origins=yes ./a.out

giving me only line 2 which is the start int proc()
==469== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==469== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==469== Using Valgrind-3.24.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==469== Command: ./a.out
==469==
==469== Syscall param exit_group(status) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==469==    at 0x4CC909D: _Exit (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==469==    by 0x4C26EB5: __run_exit_handlers (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==469==    by 0x4C26FFF: exit (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==469==    by 0x4C0D2B4: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==469==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==469==    at 0x401116: proc() (my_prog.cpp:2)
==469==
==469==
==469== HEAP SUMMARY:
==469==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==469==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==469==
==469== For a detailed leak analysis, rerun with: --leak-check=full
==469==
==469== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==469== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

using clang++ with memory sanitizer as comparison (but I know the big burden to build all dependencies also with msan - that's why I'm using valgrind)
clang++ -g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=memory my_prog.cpp

giving me the exact location of the first uninitialized var usage in line 4 return y; and 9 int y = proc(); and then exit
==480==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x564ffb0f818a in proc() /home/linux/temp/my_prog.cpp:4:5
    #1 0x564ffb0f820a in main /home/linux/temp/my_prog.cpp:9:13
    #2 0x7fc2d66092ad in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2a2ad) (BuildId: 03f1631dc9760d3e30311fe62e15cc4baaa89db7)
    #3 0x7fc2d6609378 in __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2a378) (BuildId: 03f1631dc9760d3e30311fe62e15cc4baaa89db7)
    #4 0x564ffb05b104 in _start /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.40/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:115

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value /home/linux/temp/my_prog.cpp:4:5 in proc()
Exiting

are there some tricks, compiler settings, dbg tricks to exactly locate the variable in this unrealistic small example with the output of valgrind? (give that my real scenarios are way bigger and older)
ANOTHER SCENARIO:
small example - but in real that uninitialized access is somewhere hidden under +100k lines of inline code - too large functions (not developed by me) to get a fast clue from which var the problem comes from
using UBSAN (and MSAN as example) and -Werror -Wall
no UBSAN warnings, no ASAN warnings only MSAN(very detailed) or Valgrind with just the main as the start point were it happens - but in my real scenario there are much much more variables cluttered over the whole function (as an example)
what can I do now to get more out of the valgrind info (additional options, other complementing tools helping valgrind?) - to be better prepared for the future or for extending my CI server to also give out better information
MSAN is out of scope because there are 20 third-party libs used (and not even all in source available) - the reason for using valgrind
and I'm only interested in uninitialized memory findings - ASAN is already in use for years for finding other memory related problems
union blub_t
{
    short a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    blub_t g;
    g.a = 10;
    return g.b;
}

build + valgrind
clang++ -g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Werror -Wall my_prog.cpp
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=no --track-origins=yes ./a.out

gives
==636== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==636== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==636== Using Valgrind-3.24.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==636== Command: ./a.out
==636==
==636== Syscall param exit_group(status) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==636==    at 0x4CC909D: _Exit (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==636==    by 0x4C26EB5: __run_exit_handlers (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==636==    by 0x4C26FFF: exit (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==636==    by 0x4C0D2B4: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6)
==636==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==636==    at 0x401116: main (my_prog.cpp:8)
==636==
==636==
==636== HEAP SUMMARY:
==636==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==636==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==636==
==636== For a detailed leak analysis, rerun with: --leak-check=full
==636==
==636== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==636== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

build with MSAN
clang++ -g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=memory,undefined -Werror -Wall my_prog.cpp

gives
==585==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x559d2f9471ec in main /home/linux/temp/my_prog.cpp:11:5
    #1 0x7f47941bf2ad in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2a2ad) (BuildId: 03f1631dc9760d3e30311fe62e15cc4baaa89db7)
    #2 0x7f47941bf378 in __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2a378) (BuildId: 03f1631dc9760d3e30311fe62e15cc4baaa89db7)
    #3 0x559d2f8aa104 in _start /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.40/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:115

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value /home/linux/temp/my_prog.cpp:11:5 in main
Exiting


Value returned by proc is not used in any observable way (unlike return x;), so I guess valgrind doesn't care about it.

Actually it's surprising that sanitizer detects call to proc() as offending code, looks like false-positive, because this value is not used in any way.

@pptaszni
update the example: valgrind cares in both variants - but gives less exact positions as msan, is -O0 so there is no dead code elimination active

Yep, after edit valgrind detects the use of uninitialized var on return statement. It just shows only 1 origin, either int x; or proc(), not both of them at the same time though.

OT: UPDATE and similar dont make the question easier to read but rather the opposite. Don't require the reader of the current state of the question to be aware of all the edit history. If they want to see it they can already do that here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79233169/revisions

@pptaszni my question is not about detecting at all but how to find the exact variable (using valgrind output) if that is someway possible - because my real world scenarios are way bigger and older - having only a "its somewhere in main" is not that easy to fix :) - but i understand that is technically not an easy task for valgrind - but maybe in combination with other tools/tips?

compiler settings: -Werror -Wall :  https://godbolt.org/z/8s18KfWzd

Is there a reason why you use valgrind and not the built-in address sanitizer from gcc? You can use it with -fsanitize=address. The reports are usually quite good and readable. In this case It does not report any problem, but the -Wall flag (as in the comment from 463035818_is_not_an_ai) reports this problem with the exact location.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai

i just can't use -Werror -Wall in this legacy mio lines of code monster :/ - but i will try to use -Werror=uninitialized, but that does not help for example with a union that initalizes element1 and miss-uses different size element2 - its not always easy to detect such cases just by warnings - in legacy projects


@Thibe - ASAN does not detect unitialized value access, but MSAN (see my -fsanitizer=memory) is a huge burden because you need to build all dependent libraries (in depth) + libc with MSAN

-Werror -Wall does not detect union miss-use (which in itself is undefined behavior - maybe UBSAN - maybe for this small example but not my real mio lines legacy project) - example:
https://godbolt.org/z/5Gjxbr7W8

my real project is mio lines of code and two decades under development - daily checked on CI-Server with ASAN/TSAN/PVS,... i found an bug with valgrind (in my case this union thing) and just want to find out how to better use the valgrind info - the other tips are nice but sometimes hardly adaptable to the project im working on - due to the size (more warnings are defined as errors now, etc.) - the question is just valgrind info related - not "how to find problems in these 11 lines of code"

we cannot help you with million lines of code, but if you can isolate 1 issue to a [mcve] we can help you with that. I am afraid your little more realistic example is too much simplified to be of much use

in other words, don't expect answers to give you a solution that works for everything when they are given based on a specific example. Make your question focused and specific and others will answer that. Currently its difficult, because you reject the obvious ways but its not clear in the question that they  are out

@463035818_is_not_an_ai - i added ANOTHER SCENARIO - its hard to come up with an "minimal reproducible example" for "how can i get more out of valgrinds output"

What about just using the appropriate compiler flags ? -Wall -Wextra should give you more warnings, including for the use of initialized variables. Valgrind is an overkill here, unless I overlooked something ?

@Fareanor: see the ANOTHER SCENARIO i added and -Werror -Wall -Wextra gets me nothing and the question is more broad how to get more information out of valgrind - im not suffering with a problem in this small example - i want to use valgrind results faster (because i already use all other tools automaticly for years) - all state in the ANOTHER SCENARIO - its not always possible to projects im working on to add -Werror -Wall -Wextra and start fixing - my current project got 1mio lines of code - the "uninitalized memory" info is just not detailed enough and i hoped for some tips

I'll see if I can fix this.

@Paul Floyd - Hello Mr. Valgrind - it would be really nice if the position information for unititalized values could be just a tiny little bit better :) - i know its super-not-easy

@Paul Floyd - would be also great to have an option to let valgrind only check for uninitalized values (if that is not already available) - this way i can do my big long-running tests with ASAN - and the stuff that ASAN can't handle with valgrind (but faster because all other memory test ommitted)

If I change the code to be
#include "valgrind/memcheck.h"

int proc()
{
    int easy_to_find;
    (void)VALGRIND_CHECK_MEM_IS_DEFINED(&easy_to_find, sizeof(easy_to_find));
    return easy_to_find;
}

int main()
{
    int y = proc();
    int x;
    return x+y;
}

then with the right options
valgrind --track-origins=yes --read-var-info=yes ./so13
==395216== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==395216== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==395216== Using Valgrind-3.25.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==395216== Command: ./so13
==395216== 
==395216== Uninitialised byte(s) found during client check request
==395216==    at 0x401378: proc() (so13.cpp:7)
==395216==    by 0x401394: main (so13.cpp:13)
==395216==  Location 0x1ffefff25c is 0 bytes inside local var "easy_to_find"
==395216==  declared at so13.cpp:6, in frame #0 of thread 1
==395216==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==395216==    at 0x401326: proc() (so13.cpp:5)
==395216== 
==395216== Syscall param exit_group(status) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==395216==    at 0x512F336: _Exit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==395216==    by 0x5077DC9: __run_exit_handlers (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==395216==    by 0x5077DFF: exit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==395216==    by 0x50617EB: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==395216==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==395216==    at 0x401326: proc() (so13.cpp:5)
==395216== 
==395216== 
==395216== HEAP SUMMARY:
==395216==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==395216==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==395216== 
==395216== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==395216== 
==395216== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==395216== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

I think that the problem is that the error occurs after the return from proc(). The dwarfdump for the exe gives me
0x000002a2:   DW_TAG_subprogram
                DW_AT_external  (true)
                DW_AT_name      ("proc")
                DW_AT_decl_file ("/path/to/so13.cpp")
                DW_AT_decl_line (4)
                DW_AT_decl_column       (0x05)
                DW_AT_linkage_name      ("_Z4procv")
                DW_AT_type      (0x0000029b "int")
                DW_AT_low_pc    (0x0000000000401326)
                DW_AT_high_pc   (0x0000000000401388)
                DW_AT_frame_base        (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
                DW_AT_call_all_calls    (true)
                DW_AT_sibling   (0x00000306)

0x000002c8:     DW_TAG_variable
                  DW_AT_name    ("easy_to_find")
                  DW_AT_decl_file       ("/path/to/so13.cpp")
                  DW_AT_decl_line       (6)
                  DW_AT_decl_column     (0x09)
                  DW_AT_type    (0x0000029b "int")
                  DW_AT_location        (DW_OP_fbreg -20)

I'm not really a DWARF expert, but I think that means that with the instruction pointer is between DW_AT_low_pc and DW_AT_high_pc it's possible to use the DW_TAG_variable to get the file and line info from the address calculated from the function DW_AT_frame_base and the variable location DW_OP_fbreg -20. There's also a lexical scope for the variable that I missed out.
All that to say that I don't think that it is feasible. At the point where the error happens, after main, we no longer have the values of the instruction pointer or frame poiner necessary to get the source file information from the DWARF debuginfo.
I'll take a look at the info that --track-origins=yes retains to see if that could be extended to get more information.

thanks for the feedback - loved to test anything you come up with regarding origin tracking
